# How do I center list in div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How can I center list in the nav? I would like to list with content, to be centered in "nav", and li's height, to be same as nav's height. It's my first post in English, so please be understanding.

```css
header
{
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 4.5vw;
}
nav
{
  background: #3095d3;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-flex;
}
ul
{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
}
ul > li
{
  padding: 1vw;
  float: left;
  font-size: 2.5vw;
}

li:hover
{
  background: #50B5F3;
}
```

```html
  <header>
    Anon
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>cont1</li>
        <li>cont2</li>
        <li>cont3</li>
        <li>cont4</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add `margin: auto` to your `ul` element.

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/mn9vvfpn/)

Comment: you should also set `padding: 0` so it's truly centered.

Comment: Thanks, very thanks! :D It was stupid :D

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `inline-flex` on `nav` you can just add `justify-content: center`.

Though from the look of it, `nav` should probably just be `flex`, then you can remove `width: 100%`, too.

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 4.5vw;
}

nav {
  background: #3095d3;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul > li {
  padding: 1vw;
  font-size: 2.5vw;
  float: left;
}

li:hover {
  background: #50B5F3;
}
```

```html
<header>
  Anon
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>cont1</li>
      <li>cont2</li>
      <li>cont3</li>
      <li>cont4</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```